# I get a SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault, when I try to write to wxListBox ( C++, wxWidgets, CodeBlocks )

Tags: c++

The program I am writing can build and get executed from CodeBlocks IDE, but pressing a specific button ( invoking a handler function ) makes program crash. In debugger mode I get this message :

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
```

And it happens in the line :

```
m_listboxSorted->SetString(k, "some text");
```

---

Minimal version of my program, that I hope includes all the important parts of code, is :

```
class MainFrame: public wxFrame
{
public:    
wxListBox *m_listboxSorted;    
};

bool TestApp::OnInit()
{
MainFrame* OurMainFrame = new MainFrame(constructor info... );
OurMainFrame->Show( true );
return true;
}


MainFrame::MainFrame(constructor info...)
{
wxListBox * m_listboxSorted = new wxListBox(constructor info...);
}

void MainFrame::ButtonClicked(wxCommandEvent & event)
{

    static unsigned int k = 0 ;
    k++;
    m_listboxSorted->SetString(k, "some text"); // !! Problematic line !!
}
```

Now, after searching online for solution to the *signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault* I figured that the problem must be in the pointer, and dereferencing it. But as a beginner, I was unsuccessful in applying this information to solve my program issue.

**EDIT :** 
I have also tried to change this line :

```
wxListBox *m_listboxSorted;
```

with this one:

```
wxListBox *m_listboxSorted = new wxListBox;
```

But this time, when pressing the button ( invoking the handler function ), I get this message :

[image: Error Message]

---

What to correct in my code to make the program function properly ?

Comment: Upvoted for clear question and for actually debugging the problem before posting on SO :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The member `wxListBox *m_listboxSorted;` is uninitialized.

> wxListBox * m_listboxSorted = new wxListBox(constructor info...);

in the constructor does not assign a value to the member, but instead declares a local pointer which is leaked when the constructor returns.

> m_listboxSorted->SetString(k, "some text");

then dereferences the uninitialized member pointer resulting in undefined behaviour.

To fix, remove the type from the line in constructor so that it becomes an assignment rather than a declaration.

Comment: Changing the line "wxListBox * m_listboxSorted = new wxListBox(constructor info...)" to "m_listboxSorted = new wxListBox(constructor info...)" did the trick, thank you !